# How to connect RStudio to OneDrive Excel file?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, onedrive, dbi

Currently trying to connect to a OneDrive file that contains a spreadsheet. Trying to pull some IDs from the file. What packages might achieve this?

Can the DBI package connect to OneDrive?

Comment: You can run OneDrive on your machine and have it sync to a folder, then read the file from there.

Answer (score 1):

AS suggested by @chthonicdaemon you could install OneDrive locally, sync the file and use it exactly as a local file.

But there are other options - the most obvious being:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/od_sp.html